# How to add subView to ViewGroup using RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: android, viewgroup

I wrote a class that extends ViewGroup and override the method as follow:

```
 @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    for(int index = 0; index < getChildCount(); index++){
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            View child = getChildAt(index);
            child.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width,
                    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec
                    .makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    }
}
```

When I add subView to this viewGroup as follow:

```
String word = words[random.nextInt(words.length)];
            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(DraggableGridViewSampleActivity.this);
            TextView text = new TextView(DraggableGridViewSampleActivity.this);
            text.setText(word);
            ImageView view = new ImageView(DraggableGridViewSampleActivity.this);
            view.setImageBitmap(getThumb(word));
            layout.addView(view);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            layout.addView(text, params);
            dgv.addView(layout);
```

The effect is like: The textView can't be displayed completely. It seems that the parent view doesn't provide enough space for the textview to display.

How to have the textView displayed completely?

Comment: share some snapshot of how does it look now ! Doing this in xml is much easier btw

Comment: sorry, I don't have the authority

Answer (score 0):

> The textView can't be displayed completely. It seems that the parent
>   view doesn't provide enough space for the textview to display.

What exactly are you trying to do with the `onMeasure` method? Right now you're letting the super class handle an initial measure of the children(`super.onMeasure`) and then you remeasure the children again, this time giving them a `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`, basically telling the children they could be as big as they want.

You should always respect the `MeasureSpec` when you're measuring the children(or the parent should allow scrolling). If the parent says that the children should be `AT_MOST` 500 px then don't potentially step over this value when measuring the children by giving them a `MeasureSpec` of `UNSPECIFIED`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer very much. But when I change the UNSPECIFIED with EXACTLY, the "params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);" seems no effect. How can I tell the child its exact size and make the params usedul?

Comment: @BigFootprint Are you sure the rules aren't followed? The problem , is if simply modify the `UNSPECIFIED` to `EXACTLY` the child will still occupy the full width of the parent as you're passing the entire width of the parent as the size(`int width`). Instead of that `width` use a smaller value like `100`(or something smaller than the width of the parent) and see how it goes.

Comment: Nothing happend. The change of width doesn't affect the UI. It's so strange.

Comment: @BigFootprint Where do you add the custom `ViewGroup` class? With which `LayoutParams` are you adding it to its parent?

Comment: The ViewGroup is used as the contentView. May I send email the code to you?

Comment: @BigFootprint Send it. I'll have a look at it in the afternoon

Comment: I have sent it yestoday. Did you receive it?

Comment: @BigFootprint Check the email.